# Comparing string with various numbers in AWK

Tags: linux, awk

It's much easier to explain it with an example:

Say I have strings like these

```
stringhead034endstring 12
stringhead212endstring 32
stringhead234endstring 23
```

so they're all in the format `stringhead???endstring`

How could I manipulate and play around with them in a group regardless of the number they posses, say, store them in an array `mystring[$1]`? If I tried that, they all would be different.

If not sure if the question is clear, so I will try to elaborate.

I'm trying to store all those strings in one single array element, say myarray["mystring"], and manipulate the data next to them. I'm using something like this

```
{ myarray[$1] += ($1 == "mystring???endstring") * $2 } # Add the value if true
```

However, this would obviously not work as there are several different strings all differentiated by the number they have, but I wanna disregard that.

Desired output is something like `mystringendstring 67`

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
stringhead034endstring 12
stringhead212endstring 32
stringhead234endstring 23

$ awk '$1 ~ /stringhead.{3}endstring/{ sum += $2 } END {print "mystringendstring " sum}' ip.txt 
mystringendstring 67
```

- `$1 ~ /stringhead.{3}endstring/` match against first field. `.{3}` means any character three times. If needed, it can be changed to `[0-9]+` to match one or more number of digits or `[0-9]{3}` for exactly three digits
- Question mentions single element array, so I've taken liberty to use a simple variable instead and serves the purpose to get expected output as mentioned by OP

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly :

```
% awk '{
   num=gensub(/stringhead([0-9]+)endstring/, "\\1", 1, $1);
   arr[$1] += num * $2
}
END{
    for (a in arr) {print a, arr[a]}
}' file
```

#### OUTPUT

```
stringhead034endstring 408
stringhead234endstring 5382
stringhead212endstring 6784
```

Comment: I'm not home up to test this on my Linux machine, but I think I wasn't very clear in the question, which is my fault. The expected output could be something like `stringheadendstring 67`, which is all numbers added, not each one individually.